# "TextSentences" function issue

Tags: list-manipulation, text, wikipedia

I currently run Mathematica 10.4.1.0 on a MAC OS X x86 (32-bit, 64-bit Kernel).

I was going through the MMA documentation looking up the function **TextSentences** and how to use it in code. I ran through a problem evaluating one of the examples that resembles what I was trying to accomplish in my own code. The code (coming straight from MMA documentation) I was trying to run is:

```
TextSentences[WikipediaData["dolphin"], 3]
```

In the documenation this gives an output that looks as per the image below:
[image: What the output is supposed to look like!]

but actually when I try to evaluate this example, I get the error message:
"*TextSentences::arg1: String or list of strings expected at position 1. >>*" which shows in the image below:
[image: The output I receive]

I was wondering if this is something caused by my machine or if I am missing some installation requirement (like a plugin or something similar). I say this because this function seems to have been introduced in MMA 10.1 and it should be working as the documentation indicates.

Appreciate the help.

Comment: Works fine ([Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s8Z9Z.png)).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the stated problem occurred perhaps due to transitory reasons that can't be replicated anymore.